# Python: TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, parsing, exception, typeerror, gpx

I have a .gpx file which is cut off int the middle of the file. When I try to parse it using the [gpxpy library](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy) I run into the following error.

```
Parsing points in track.gpx
ERROR:root:expected '>', line 3125, column 29
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpxpy-0.8.7-py2.7.egg/gpxpy/parser.py", line 209, in parse
    self.xml_parser = LXMLParser(self.xml)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpxpy-0.8.7-py2.7.egg/gpxpy/parser.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.dom = mod_etree.XML(self.xml)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2734, in lxml.etree.XML (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54411)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1578, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82748)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1457, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81546)
  File "parser.pxi", line 965, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78216)
  File "parser.pxi", line 569, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74472)
  File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75363)
  File "parser.pxi", line 590, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74696)
XMLSyntaxError: expected '>', line 3125, column 29

File "gpxscript.py", line 370, in extractpoints gpx = gpxpy.parse(file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpxpy-0.8.7-py2.7.egg/gpxpy/__init__.py",
     line 28, in parse raise mod_gpx.GPXException('Error parsing {0}: {1}'
                       .format(xml_or_file[0 : 100], parser.get_error()))
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

These are the relevant commands of the script which produces the error.

```
368  file = open(filepath)
369  try:
370      gpx = gpxpy.parse(file)
371  except gpxpy.gpx.GPXException:
372      print "GPXException for %s." % filepath
373      return 1
```

---

I filed a [bug for the library](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/issues/10) as suggested. I added a sample file to the bug report which produces the syntax error.

Comment: It's quite possible that there's a minor bug in `gpxpy`'s error handling, so when it detects a corrupt file is raises the wrong exception. But without a complete sample (including, most importantly, a link to your corrupt file) it would be pretty hard for anyone to figure out whether or not that's the case.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code… I think I _can_ guess.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in the library; it is trying to limit the filename to 100 characters but that fails if you handed it a file object instead of a filename.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Nope, it's got a function which is documented to take a file object or a string, and which "mostly" works in both cases, except that the error handling code assumes it's a string. (Also, some of the underlying libraries it uses may not work the way it expects both ways.)

Comment: @abarnert: That is what I said, or so I thought at least. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No, it's not a filename, it's file _contents_.

Comment: @abarnert: same difference. :-P filename-shmilename!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `gpxpy`'s error handling.

Looking at the source to [`parse`](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/master/gpxpy/__init__.py#L17), when the parser fails without raising an exception, it tries to raise an exception with this:

```
raise mod_gpx.GPXException('Error parsing {0}: {1}'.format(xml_or_file[0 : 100], parser.get_error()))
```

This assumes that `xml_or_file` is an XML string—but, as the name implies, it's allowed to be either a string *or a file object*. So, what you're doing (giving it a file object) is perfectly legal and should work, and it doesn't, and therefore it's a bug.

So, you should [file an issue](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/issues). The correct patch should be something like:

```
if not parser.is_valid():
    try:
        fragment = xml_or_file[0 : 100]
    except TypeError:
        xml_or_file.seek(0)
        fragment = xml_or_file.read(100)
    raise mod_gpx.GPXException('Error parsing {0}: {1}'.format(fragment, parser.get_error()))
```

---

So, how do you work around this? A few options:

1. Since it only happens with invalid files anyway, you can just use `except Exception` or `except (gpxpy.gpx.GPXException, TypeError)`.
2. Since it only happens when you give it a the file object, give it a string instead: `gpx = gpx.parse(file.read())`. This is a bad idea if the file is very large, of course.
3. Since the buggy function is only 12 lines of trivial code wrapping the real function, just use the real function directly. Or, if you like the wrapper, copy it, fix it, and use your own copy instead.

---

Meanwhile, given that the very first bit of code I looked at in this library has some obvious red flags (Why `xml_or_file[0 : 100]` instead of just `xml_or_file[:100]`? Why catch exceptions, throw them away and just set a flag, and then use that flag to raise a new exception with all the information missing?), if you're not able to debug libraries on your own, I don't think this one is ready for you to use.

Comment: I updated my post to show the full error log. The reason for the failure is a XMLSyntaxError. Sorry for cutting off this information. It became obvious when I catched the generic `Exception` as you suggested.

Comment: @JJD: If you're going to catch generic `Exception`, you may want to do `except Exception as e:` and then `print "GPXException (%r) for %s: %s." % (type(e), filepath, e)` or something. It will be much easier to debug your code later if your logs tell you what error you're getting instead of just that there's some error or other.

Comment: FYI: [Tomo Krajina rewrote the library.](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/issues/10#issuecomment-17116590) Would you comment on the change please?

Comment: Well, he definitely fixed that bug, and the new version looks better at a quick glance. It might have been even better to rely on [PEP 3134](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) for chaining exceptions in Py3 and faking something similar in Py2, rather than coming up with a custom protocol with `original_exception`. As for the `GPXXMLSyntaxException`, I agree with you that it may not be necessary, but it certainly doesn't hurt anything—it's a subclass of `GPXException`, so you can just handle the superclass if you don't care about the distinction.

Comment: I agree @abarnert, I was thinking about something like cause but didn't know of PEP 3134. The main problem why I decided to use a wrapper Exception (but keep the original message and log the original exception) is that I have no guarantee that a XMLSyntaxError is expected from a invalid XML file. If somebody uses minidom -- the same code will throw another exception (ExpatError) for another user who uses lxml. (Gpxpy can use both minidom or lxml to parse XML)

Anyway, I'll probably use you suggestion to fake something like PEP3134 for py2.